# convert from JSX to React.createElement

Tags: reactjs

I'm new using react and I'd like to convert from JSX to only react language.

So I have this JSX:

```
<div class="films" key={data.id}>{data.title} {data.releaseYear}</div>
```

I tried to convert:

```
React.createElement('div', { className: "films", id: data.id }, { data.title } );
```

but I got no success. Any ideas how to correct it?

my full code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { movies: [] }
  }


  async componentDidMount() {
    await axios.get('movies.json')
      .then(response => this.setState({ movies: response.data.movies }))
  }

  renderUsers() {
    const { movies } = this.state

    return movies.map( data => (
      <div class="films" key={data.id}>{data.title} {data.releaseYear}</div>

    ))
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, this.renderUsers());
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What do mean with no succes? Does it render a div, or do you get an error?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost/movies.js: Unexpected token, expected , (21:38)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass on the last argument as a string to React.createElement since there are not more nested level children

```
renderUsers() {
    const { movies } = this.state

    return movies.map( data => React.createElement('div', {className: 'films', key: data.id}, 
       `${data.title} ${data.releaseYear}`
    ))
  }
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { movies: [] }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({
        movies: [{id: 1, title: 'Shutter Island', releaseYear: '2010'}, {id: 2, title: 'Jane Tu ya Jaane na', releaseYear: '2011'}]
       })
    })
    
  }

  renderUsers() {
    const { movies } = this.state

    return movies.map( data => React.createElement('div', {className: 'films', key: data.id}, 
       `${data.title} ${data.releaseYear}`
    ))
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, this.renderUsers());
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Comment: thank you very much! I also notice that you remove my async and wait, is that wrong? thanks!

Comment: @RickJoem No that isn't wrong. I just removed it because in my case I wasn't making an API call for demo but using a mock data. However, you don't need to ue async await if you are using .then

Comment: I also change `ReactDOM.render(
 React.createElement(App, null), 
 document.getElementById('container')
)` now I don't need babel in my project.